# How to to do a line graph from a scatter plot?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

Considering the simple dataframe below where `step1` and `step2` are number of days after `start`.

```
id   start   step1  step2
a    0       10     27
b    0       5      45
c    0       1      11
..   ...     ...    ...
```

I'd like to plot (using `Plotly`) a graph line looking like this (a quick drawing/montage). The gray and red lines are fictional.

[image]

I've tried with `strip`, `scatter`... but without success.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you plotting against what? What is x and what is y on your sample graph? None of the red lines on your sample graph are even close to the points implied by the test data at "step1", "step2".

Comment: @MartinBrown the gray and red lines are fictional (it's a quick "montage" from a graph found of internet); in my desired graph, there is no red lines!

Comment: See this one in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#line-and-scatter-plots) first. Next, when you fail to draw the intended graph, post its output diagram and code. Please also add reproducible data.

Comment: @r-beginners I've already tried this one. But it does not connect multiple "columns", just 2 quantitative data...

Comment: You need to show us enough of your data that it is possible to draw some sort of X-Y graph say 10 to 20 data points and 2, 3 or 4 channels together with timestamps or whatever it is they are supposed to be plotted against. You should be able to get a quick look see XY chart plot in Excel (or clone thereof) or GNUplot with a steeper learning curve.

Comment: can you explain your expected output in more detail? do you want each `id` to have its own line composed of three points `(start, start_value), (step1, step1_value), (step2, step2_value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Python API

Let's say, we use [Python API reference for plotly](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/index.html) and [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to represent data. Then we can do the required plotting with help of [plotly.express.line](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html).

Here's some dummy data to experiment with:

```py
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(0)
size = 10
data = {
    'id': [*ascii_lowercase][:size]
    , 'start': rng.integers(0, 10, size)
    , 'step1': rng.integers(3, 15, size)
    , 'step2': rng.integers(6, 20, size)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

We can get a plot similar to the expected one as follows:

```py
import plotly.express as pe

(
    pe
    .line(df.set_index('id').T, title='Number of days', line_shape='spline')
    .update_layout(xaxis_title='steps', yaxis_title='days')
)
```

If we pass the DataFrame without specifying the x and y axis, then all columns are used to draw lines. So we need the `[start, step1, step2]` values to be arranged in columns and the `id` to be used as the names of those columns. Therefore, `df.set_index('id').T` is passed as the drawing data.

[image: line plot]

#### JavaScript API

In JS, the approach depends on what meaning is given to the word *dataframe*. Let's build some data ourselves, adding traces one by one to the list, which we can use in [Plotly.newPlot](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlynewplot):

```js
var steps = ['start', 'step1', 'step2'];
var trace_id = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var days = [
  [8, 10,  9],
  [6, 13, 17],
  [5,  9, 15],
  [2, 10,  6],
  [3, 14, 11],
  [0, 11, 18],
  [0, 10, 13],
  [0,  9,  6],
  [1,  9, 16],
  [8, 14, 16]];

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  var trace = {
    x: steps,
    y: days[i],
    name: trace_id[i],
    mode: 'lines',
    line: {shape: 'spline'}
  };
  data.push(trace);
}

var layout = {
  title: 'Number of days'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```